# Get database table columns where DEFAULT value is not set

Tags: php, database, mariadb

We recently updated our mariadb version and it is more strict on default column values, meaning if they are not set and not defined on insert it does not insert a new row. I am looking for a quick way to update all of the database columns that do not have a default value.

I imagine the code should look something like this, keep in mind this is only a pseudo code that I imagine and running this is not going to work:

```
$result = dbquery("SHOW TABLES");
   while ($row = dbarray($result))
   {
      foreach ($row as $key => $table)
      {
         // this is the query where it should check
         // if default value is set or not, but could not find information on how to do so
         $result2 = dbquery("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table WHERE DEFAULT IS NOT SET");

         while ($column = dbarray($result2))
         {
           // SETTING A DEFAULT VALUE
           dbquery("ALTER $table ALTER $column SET DEFAULT NULL");
         }
      }
   }
```

**NOTE: DISABLING STRICT MODE IS NOT A SOLUTION THAT I AM LOOKING FOR IN CURRENT TIME**

Any ideas on how to select the columns where the default value is not set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not providing a value for a nullable column is OK, so I suspect that you want to identify non-nullable column that have no default.

You could get that information from [`information_schema.columns`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-columns-table/):

```
select table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_default is null and isnullable = 'NO'
```

From there on, you would need to decide which value should be used as a default; the answer does depends on your actual requirement and of the datatype of the column.